# Single word for "product or service"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that can represent the phrase "product or service" as in this sentence:

Companies won't succeed unless they can provide a wanted **product or service** at a fair price.

Comment: 'thing'?  You are getting so general the word isn't going to add much value.

Comment: Or how about 'can provide for customer's wants/needs at a fair price' ?

Comment: Forget it. There isn't a single word in general use, which is why in many contexts people often use *products* (or *commodities*) to mean both physical items *and* services.

Comment: maybe *commodity*? (In economics, a commodity is a marketable item produced to satisfy wants or needs.)

Comment: @medica: "Commodity" has several meanings, some of which suggest something quite different. "**Product or service** that is **for sale**" (marketed) is as good as it gets, IMO.

Comment: Economists use the word "goods" to represent products and services.  It has two problems: many people think "goods" means only products and not services; and "goods" is often confused with "good" (especially in the entirely unrelated phrases "public good" and "public goods").

Comment: I expect commodities to be tangible. In French it means *amenity* (services), in America it means corn and stuff (goods).

Comment: Also https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-single-word-for-Goods-Services and http://ask.metafilter.com/241367/What-single-word-describes-these-things-that-my-employer-sells

Comment: I would suggest "deliverable"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Offerings** works quite well.

> a thing produced or manufactured for entertainment or sale. –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Offerings&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=offerings%20definition)

"Companies won't succeed unless they can provide their *offerings* at a fair price."

Comment: Offerings are synonymous to promotions. `Products`, or `product` for the sentence in question, should be the accepted answer since `product` includes both products & services and is just a common misnomer to think it just includes tangible goods.

Answer (score 18):

By the [definition used in economics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28business%29), *products* include services!  Not all products have to be tangible goods.  It is perfectly acceptable to say, for example, that a haircut is a product of a barbershop.

Answer (score 2):

**Good**, but that seems to be more of a product and less of a service.

'produce wanted goods' sounds not bad.

Answer (score 2):

In Canada the term chosen to describe the scope of a Federal tax was "Goods and Services Tax" (GST). The same choice of words is used by the Antipodeans.

Answer (score 2):

About the closest I've found is - solution. 
Companies won't succeed unless they can provide a solution at a fair price.

The other candidate is - proposition.
Companies won't succeed unless their proposition is at a fair price.

Comment: Neither "solution" nor "proposition" has anything to do, necessarily, with products, services, or selling (the market).

Comment: @Drew, "solution" is actually a good word. Selling products and services = selling solutions.

Comment: @Pacerier: Please reread: **necessarily**. Solutions to many things have nothing to do with products, services, or selling. A given product or service might be a solution for some problem, but not all solutions are products or services.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest "output" as a general term which may refer to physical products or services altogether.

Comment: This is a very **bad** choice, IMO.  (1) It is vague to the point of having nothing necessarily to do with (a) production or (b) service or (c) the market (selling).  Using this term to replace what was wanted removes all useful meaning.  But since this was chosen perhaps the question as posed does not really reflect what was wanted (i.e., the real question).

Comment: @JOSH, Lol.. frankly this is quite hilarious. You should know the 5k views to this page are from marketers looking for a *hyppy* term and the word "output" is nothing cool at all.

Comment: This is not an ideal choice purely from a language perspective because it depends on the context. If we are talking about the consumer, then output no longer makes sense, so ideally there would be a context insensitive word (as both "service", "product" and "good" are).

Answer (score 1):

> Companies won't succeed unless they can provide a wanted product or service at a fair price.

You could replace the phrase "provide a wanted product or service" with "meet a market demand". The phrase "market demand" can be seen as covering both products and services. As amended, it would be:

*Companies won't succeed unless they can meet a market demand at a fair price.*

Answer (score 0):

In some circumstances it might be better to use 'products' to refer to both goods and services, and use a word like 'goods' when you want to be specific about referring to physical commodities being sold.

---

Some other suggestions not mentioned in other answers:

- Deliverable
- Supply